# Correcting mis-typed data in R

Tags: r

I want to correct wrongly entered data in R. For example if I have a vector

```
V=c('PO','PO','P0')
```

I want R to recognize that the 0 in the last entry should be a o and to change it. Is there anyway to do that? I have trying to use  correctTypos in the deducorrect package in R. However I am having some problem with the editset. I cannot seems to specify that all the entries have to be letters. Any help greatly appreciated.

Another example would be

```
V2=c('PL','P1','PL','XX')
```

That 1 should be an L.

Comment: As in `sub("0", "O", V)`?

Comment: @markus Yes but its not that simple. I need R to recognize that it is suppose to do that. That if there is anything other than letters that it is wrong and to then come up with the correction.

Comment: Can you share some more data then that mimics your problem.

Comment: This seems to be a question about the `deducorrect` package and alternatives. Can you share what you tried to do with  the `correctTypos()` function?

Comment: Are you expecting R to recognise "0" should be "O" because those 2 look the same?
That's quite a hard question for a function, as it basically has nothing to do with 0 or O, for a computer it doesn't matter they look "about the same" when printed. So you'll have to tell R that anyway, for a function it makes just as much sense to replace "0" with "Z".

Comment: Welcome to SO. R has no magical capabilities nor the ability to intuit what you want. It's a general purpose programming language and you would need to code up heuristics to account for errors in input or use the packages others have suggested to do it. It will require effort/work.

Answer (score 0):

The jaro-winkler distance was developed to find issues with data entry. But on entries only 2 long that is going to be difficult as 1 error tends to score higher than you want it to. You could combine this with other distance measurements available in the stringdist package. But in this case that might be too complicated.

Given your examples you might want to use the base function `chartr` and set up a replacement of numbers to letters.

```
chartr("01","OL", V2)
[1] "PL" "PL" "PL" "XX"

chartr("01","OL", V)
[1] "PO" "PO" "PO"
```

This will always replace the 1 by an L and a 0 (zero) by an O. You can add the 5 for S etc etc. But if there are other combo's it might get complicated.

Also note that the next iteration of the deducorrect package is the deductive package.